# MySql Structure Check and Suggestion

Tags: mysql

Please forgive me if this is not the correct place for this question.

A while back while working on a Mysql database I come across something that did a check on the database and the database structure and provided a sort of report that gave suggestions on what types/lengths/values to be used based on the data in the database.

I have been searching for this and just cant seem to find it again, has any come across anything like this or know where I can find this again.

Currently using phpmyadmin and also had a look on Navicat

Comment: I imagine Workbench includes these tools

Comment: I was also thinking that but cant seem to find it in workbench either